# Download from multiple links in python and store it in multiple list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, wget

```py
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import urllib.request

import wget

df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/ZAM/Desktop/cik_list.xlsx")

df = df.iloc[:,5:]

df['add_http'] = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/"

df = df.astype(str)

df.columns

urls = []

length = len(df)

for i in range(length):

    df['new_col'] = df['add_http'] + df['SECFNAME'] 

    urls.append(df['new_col'])

df = df.iloc[:,2:]

print(urls[i])
```

```
#OUTPUT

0      https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0...

1      https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0...
2      https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0...
3      https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0...
4      https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0...
                             ...                        
147    https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/12239/...
148    https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/12239/...
149    https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/12239/...
150    https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/12239/...
151    https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/12239/...
```

I want to download the data in the above 152 links and store it directly in a variable/list (not sure) or either I can download data from these links and import them in python. Please provide solutions for both.

NOTE: The data consists of texts and I want to perform sentimental analysis on it and I believe that storing it in a list will create a problem as I won't be able to read the data separately as a list[1] will have the entire text from a single link.

Let me know if there is a way.
Thanks!

Comment: Use beautifulsoup and get the complete text in the website, i that is what you are looking for to save.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you trying to download each file and keep their data separately in a list? If so, wouldn't it be better to individually read each file when you need them since loading all of them at once would probably make you go over any memory limits?

Comment: Thanks, Sundeep Pidugu I will look at what beautiful soup is.

Comment: @Axiumin_ Yes I had the same thing in mind but there are 153 links and changing the code and running the code for so many times will be hectic. It's better I create a function and loop all the data in it. Let me know what you think. Thanks